# Partition tables based on month and year in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a sales table which I need to partition based on month and year of sales

table structure

```
S_ID           numeric(18,0)
S_CustID       numeric(18,0)
S_TotalCash    numeric(18,0)
S_Paid         numeric(18,0)
S_Date         datetimeoffset(0)
```

I want to enter sales records between 01/01/2014 to 31/05/2014 to the first sales tables 
and from 01/06/2014 to 31/12/2014 to the second table
and use a partitioned view to insert and select records from both the table so I add a constraint as

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sales_1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_sales_1_1] CHECK  ((datepart(mm,[S_Date]) >= (01)) and (datepart(mm,[S_Date]) < (06)) and ((datepart(year,[date]) = (2014)))
```

for the first table 
and

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sales_2]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_sales_2_1] CHECK  ((datepart(mm,[S_Date]) >= (01)) and (datepart(mm,[S_Date]) < (06)) and ((datepart(year,[date]) = (2014)))
```

AND
used a partitioned view

```
Select * from Sales_1
union all 
Select * from Sales_2
```

to insert and update records
 but when I try to insert data ssms shows error as

> "UNION ALL view 'Test.dbo.Sales_View' is not updatable because a partitioning column was not found."

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, it must be said that using SQL's native table partitioning support is preferred.  But that requires SQL Enterprise, which is a lot of money, so, presumably, here we are.

A few things for you to check:

1. Partition column must be part of primary key
2. Partition column must have one and only one `CHECK` constraint
3. Partitions must not overlap.  Perhaps you have a typo, or my eyes fail me, but your constraints on `sales_1` and `sales_2` overlap.
4. Make sure the constraints are checked (`WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT`).  Given your definition in the question, it probably isn't the issue, but it is in general a necessary troubleshooting step (take a look at `SELECT name, is_not_trusted FROM sys.check_constraints`)

**EDIT**

Apparently `DATEPART` doesn't work.  Probably you should just specify the dates directly (`s_date >= '2014-01-01' AND s_date < '2014-06-01'`), etc.  You could also use persisted custom columns.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155758/partitioned-view-not-working

Some other things to note about partitioned views, most of which I ran into quickly:

1. `IDENTITY` columns will prevent inserts.  What I did to get around this was create a "staging" table with the same structure (and an identity column), and add a trigger that just inserts into the partitioned view and deletes from the staging table.  At some point I will look into using SQL 2012's `SEQUENCE`s
2. You can't run an update/delete query on the PV if it has a self-join on the PV or any of its tables
3. All columns have to be specified in an `INSERT` statement.  `DEFAULT` doesn't work or help.  You can't omit nullable columns or columns with a default value.
4. If you use replication, it tends to disable the constraints (`NOT FOR REPLICATION`), so you'll have to make sure that doesn't happen

You can see here at the bottom: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933141(v=sql.80).aspx