# Update view using derived key in Database

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, view

Is it possible to update this view by specifying the `MessageTech` and the `txtmessageID`? (`txtmessageID` and `MessageId` are the primary keys from the respective base tables.)

```
(SELECT
    txtmessageID,
    'S' AS MessageTech,
    MessageType,
    Message,
    MessageDate,
    MessageMobile,
    MessageRead,
    MessageSender
FROM
    MessageCentre)

UNION ALL

(SELECT
    MessageId,
    'E' AS MessageTech,
    Type,
    Text,
    Date,
    Address,
    [Read],
    Sender
FROM
    MessageCentreEmail)
```

Answer (score 3):

The with some modification the view should be updateable, but not in its current form.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms187956.aspx gives the rules for Partitioned Views

Some things you would need to change:

1. `MessageTech` column would need to be part of the underlying tables
2. `MessageTech` needs to be part of the primary key of each underlying table
3. `MessageTech` needs to have constraints on it in each table such that a given value could not possibly refer to more than one table e.g.

---

```
ALTER TABLE MessageCentre Add 
    MessageTech char(1) Not Null Default 'S',
    Constraint chk_MessageTechIs_S Check (MessageTech = 'S');
```

There are some other conditions too, which you can read about in that link, but those are the obvious changes that would need to occur.

Comment: Also http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58431/partition-tables-based-on-month-and-year-in-sql-server